# Unable to fetch data from controller to Vue Component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to fetch data from the database to the vue component using controller in laravel but for some reason is not showing anything on the screen, 
The data is being passed and there are no errors to be seen
The only thing i can see is the **"li"** tag dots which are way more than the entries present in the DB

**This is what i am getting:-**
[image]

**Controller:-**

```
class MyRequestController extends Controller
{
    public function MyRequest()
    {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

**Vue Component:-**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul>
                            <li v-for="user in users">{{users.email}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data()
        {
            return {
                users : []
            }
        },
        created() {
            axios.get('./userz')
            .then(response => this.users = response.data);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am still figuring out the vue in laravel so it would really help if you keep your answer simple.

**Debugging**
changes made:-

```
created() {
            axios.get('./userz')
            .then(response => this.users = response.data);
            console.log(this.users);

        }
```

OUTPUT:-
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218582/discussion-on-question-by-anonymous-chatbox-unable-to-fetch-data-from-controller). If you are asked for additional information, please [edit] it into the question (do not reply in comments). If you have suggestions on how to fix the problem, please post an answer.

Comment: Yes, you have done it right. This is a baffling issue. When you add the `:key` in the li tag, refresh and count the number of dots. See if they correspond to the number in the database.

Comment: @Tony no the dots haven't corresponded and the output is still same and the debugging has been moved to chatbox you can respond there if you dont mind

Comment: Change `users.email` to `user.email` in this line `<li v-for="user in users">{{users.email}}</li>`.

Comment: @Aashishgaba Still Same

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't solve the issue, it was just a bug that I found while reading your post. Did you try printing the response from the API, as well the data in the controller just before it returns the data ?

Comment: If you look at the vue-devtools it's showing that `users` is actually a string, not an array.  so it's probably looping over every single character which is why there are more li's than users.  What is the output if you do a `console.log(response.data)`?

Comment: @Aashishgaba You mean whether the controller is passing the data to the component or not?

Comment: Yeah, I mean firstly print the data in the controller so that we can confirm that there is some data to be sent, and then print the response in the API and check if you're getting it there.

Comment: @StevenB. `Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: response is not defined` this is the error that i am getting

Comment: @Aashishgaba I think that the data is being passed as you can see in the picture bottom right {as i am just a beginner i could be wrong} and I don't understand what do you mean by "print the response in API" and [FYI:- the route /userz is in web.php file]

Comment: Oh my bad, I meant after the API call. Oh, yeah I just saw it. You have the users as string, check that in you picture that you mentioned. it's not an array.

Comment: @Aashishgaba so how do i solve this? and can you guide me how do i print the response after the API call

Comment: To see the response add a console.log inside then 
function `axios.get('./userz').then(response => console.log(response))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218593/discussion-between-aashish-gaba-and-anonymous-chatbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the data in form of json. So, in your controller function return the users as a json response.

```
return response()->json(User::all());
```